# Creation of personal My Site Site error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, mysite, self-service

When users visit the My Site root page, they are greeted with the "We're Almost Ready!" message. Their My Site page is never created.

When I check a users Personal Site Instantiation State, it shows enqueued. When I try to create a user's My Site via PowerShell using the "`CreatePersonalSite()"` method, I get:

> "ErrorLanguageNotInstalled"

User's can create site collections within the My Site web application by visiting the site creation page (`http://[server]/_layouts/15/scsignup.aspx`).

I setup My Sites to allow any language that the user selects. Self Site creation was working in the past. Seems like it stopped working after patching/updates a couple months ago.

Comment: The "ErrorLanguageNotInstalled" is a member of SP.UserProfiles.PersonalSiteInstantiationState enumeration (
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj679733.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You need to provide the detail error message when running the commands to create My Site. Also, check ULS log for more error message about this issue.

Comment: The exception was: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PersonalSiteCreateConfigurationException: A failure was encountered while attempting to create the site; the desired language is not installed on this server.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateSite>b__0()